# How to detect the disconnected TCP connection and again connect

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services

I have a TCP/IP client program in a Windows service written in C#. As of now everything is working fine. But I have a query that supposes my connection to the machine goes down due to any reasons say machine is out of the network or something. How will my application detect that and also tries to connect or regain the connection again?

Here is the code that I am using in my Windows service:

```
private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _thread.Start();


         System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60 * 1000); // every 60 seconds
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start(); // <- important
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (client.Connected)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
        else { 
           //close the thread and again start.
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText(textfileSaveLocation))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("Disconnected!!!!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            _shutdownEvent.Set();
            _thread.Start();

        }         
     }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            string data= "";
            fileSaveLocation = location;

            try
            {
                client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error here.
                client.Close();
                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] notify = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
                    stream.Write(notify, 0, notify.Length);

                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
                    {
                        int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        if (numBytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            data= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error here.
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _shutdownEvent.Set();  // trigger the thread to stop
        _thread.Join();        // wait for thread to stop
    }
```

Please help me. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

`TcpClient` does not get notified when the connection is closed or disconnected. You can check manually if `TcpClient` is connected in every certain period like -

```
if(tcpClient.Connected)
{
     //code
}
else
{
     //renew connection
}
```

Or, you have to handle the `Exception` in Catch block and code as required.

Comment: Ok I will check this in timer for every 1 minute will it be OK

Comment: I see no harm, but it actually depends on your requirements.

Comment: OK I have updated my post with all the code alongwith timer .PLease see and guide me if it is correct or anything needs to be chnaged.Will it work?

Comment: well, i think in your case adding the Timer is irrelevant. Because, you are taking `new TcpClient()` each time inside `while` loop in `DoWork()` method. btw, you won't get `client` inside `timer_Elapsed`.

Comment: If i will initialize `new TcpClient()` in the start of the application then i can get it into `timer_Elapsed`.Will it work ?

Comment: Yes, then the total thing makes sense.

Comment: OK I will test and let you know.

Comment: I have tested the application first with connected then switching the machine off! and again switch on it again but i am not able to get the data from the machine..Please see my updated post with updated `timer_Elapsed` function

Comment: I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error in `  if (client.Connected)`.Why?

Comment: move `client` to top and initialize inside `onStart()`

Comment: I have added ` public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    { 
        TcpClient client;` and here i am initializing ` protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            client = new TcpClient();` but again same error.

Comment: `if(tcpClient.Connected)` this is not able to analysize after the connection gets `disconnected ` also

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that i am not able to get the correct state of `TCPclient` in `timer_Elapsed`